# MVC model returning null value

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-5

[Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hOKKO.jpg) [Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tQbOW.jpg)
I am quite new to MVC and this is my first question in stackoverflow, so please bear with me. I have been getting ArgumentNullException from my Customer Model. The exact same code seems to be working in VS 2013 as shown in one of my training videos but does not work in my VS 2019. Can anyone please suggest on how to fix this error?

Below is my code for the CustomersController

```
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Data.Entity;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web.Mvc;
using Vidly.Models;

namespace Vidly.Controllers
{
    public class CustomersController : Controller
    {

        private ApplicationDbContext _context;

        public CustomersController()
        {
            _context = new ApplicationDbContext();
        }

        protected override void Dispose(bool disposing)
        {
            _context.Dispose();
        }
        public ViewResult Index()
        {
            /* Eager Loading */
            var customers = _context.Customers.Include(c => c.MembershipType).ToList();   

            return View(customers);
        }

        public ActionResult Details(int id)
        {
            var customer = _context.Customers.SingleOrDefault(c => c.Id == id);

            if (customer == null)
                return HttpNotFound();

            return View(customer);
        }

        
    }
}
```

**[And this is my Customers View.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/feVU4.png)**

```
@model IEnumerable<Vidly.Models.Customer>


@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Customers";
    Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_Layout.cshtml";
}

<h2>Customers</h2>
@if (!Model.Any())
{
    <p>We don't have any customers yet.</p>
}
else
{
    <table class="table table-bordered table-hover">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>Customer</th>
                <th>Membership Type</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
            @foreach (var customer in Model)
            {
            <tr>
                <td>@Html.ActionLink(customer.Name, "Details", "Customers", new { id = customer.Id }, null)</td>
                <td>@customer.MembershipType.Name</td>

            </tr>
            }
        </tbody>
    </table>
}
```

Comment: where you exactly getting the error?

Comment: In the Customers View at the line which says @if (!Model.Any())

Comment: Show me description of this error

Comment: @TomaszVizaint Have edited my question with the link to the error description.

Comment: And this !Model.Any have some data? check this, in conditional statement normaly is true or false, or comparing with some data.

Comment: @tomasz: The model itself always returns null. I am using code first approach and i have double checked that the customers table is populated with data already. So not sure why it returns null always.

Comment: @SudhanshuJoshi hi, i had similar problem when following this tutorial. Watch the video again and if you wont see where you going wrong just have a look on his github. People following this tutorial are also posting their issues, maybe that will help you the most. Here as you can see you will only get downvotes. Maybe wee can keep on touch fellow student is always good to have!

Comment: make sure your database isn't empty!

Comment: @rykamol: It is not as I have mentioned the same earlier.

Comment: @VanessaKensington: I did what you suggested but couldn't find any solution till now. Have also posted a question on the tutorials page and waiting for a revert but its been 2 days so thought to post it here. Also, couldn't find any solution or similar problems in the GitHub. Can you DM me anywhere on how you solved it?

Comment: @SudhanshuJoshi I dont remember its been a few weeks, to be honest in the next video he will remove the part that is giving you an error anyway. I know its not the best approach but if you are stuck on this for 2 days its probably the easiest just delete it or move on

Answer (score 0):

I have checked and found no problem.

**In Controller:**

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Rendering;
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;
using Vidly.Data;
using Vidly.Models;

namespace Vidly.Controllers
{
    public class CustomersController : Controller
    {
        private readonly ApplicationDbContext _context;

        public CustomersController(ApplicationDbContext context)
        {
            _context = context;
        }

        // GET: Customers
        //public async Task<IActionResult> Index()
        //{
        //    return View(await _context.Customer.ToListAsync());
        //}

        public ViewResult Index()
        {
            /* Eager Loading */
            var customers = _context.Customers.Include(c => c.MembershipType).ToList();

            return View(customers);
        }

        // GET: Customers/Details/5
        public async Task<IActionResult> Details(int? id)
        {
            if (id == null)
            {
                return NotFound();
            }

            var customer = await _context.Customers
                .FirstOrDefaultAsync(m => m.Id == id);
            if (customer == null)
            {
                return NotFound();
            }

            return View(customer);
        }

        // GET: Customers/Create
        public IActionResult Create()
        {
            return View();
        }

        // POST: Customers/Create
        // To protect from overposting attacks, enable the specific properties you want to bind to, for 
        // more details, see http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=317598.
        [HttpPost]
        [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
        public async Task<IActionResult> Create([Bind("Id,Name,MembershipType")] Customer customer)
        {
            if (ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                _context.Add(customer);
                await _context.SaveChangesAsync();
                return RedirectToAction(nameof(Index));
            }
            return View(customer);
        }

        // GET: Customers/Edit/5
        public async Task<IActionResult> Edit(int? id)
        {
            if (id == null)
            {
                return NotFound();
            }

            var customer = await _context.Customers.FindAsync(id);
            if (customer == null)
            {
                return NotFound();
            }
            return View(customer);
        }

        // POST: Customers/Edit/5
        // To protect from overposting attacks, enable the specific properties you want to bind to, for 
        // more details, see http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=317598.
        [HttpPost]
        [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
        public async Task<IActionResult> Edit(int id, [Bind("Id,Name,MembershipType")] Customer customer)
        {
            if (id != customer.Id)
            {
                return NotFound();
            }

            if (ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                try
                {
                    _context.Update(customer);
                    await _context.SaveChangesAsync();
                }
                catch (DbUpdateConcurrencyException)
                {
                    if (!CustomerExists(customer.Id))
                    {
                        return NotFound();
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        throw;
                    }
                }
                return RedirectToAction(nameof(Index));
            }
            return View(customer);
        }

        // GET: Customers/Delete/5
        public async Task<IActionResult> Delete(int? id)
        {
            if (id == null)
            {
                return NotFound();
            }

            var customer = await _context.Customers
                .FirstOrDefaultAsync(m => m.Id == id);
            if (customer == null)
            {
                return NotFound();
            }

            return View(customer);
        }

        // POST: Customers/Delete/5
        [HttpPost, ActionName("Delete")]
        [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
        public async Task<IActionResult> DeleteConfirmed(int id)
        {
            var customer = await _context.Customers.FindAsync(id);
            _context.Customers.Remove(customer);
            await _context.SaveChangesAsync();
            return RedirectToAction(nameof(Index));
        }

        private bool CustomerExists(int id)
        {
            return _context.Customers.Any(e => e.Id == id);
        }
    }
}
```

**In View:**

```
@model IEnumerable<Vidly.Models.Customer>


@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Customers";
    Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_Layout.cshtml";
}

<h2>Customers</h2>
@if (!Model.Any())
{
    <p>We don't have any customers yet.</p>
}
else
{
    <table class="table table-bordered table-hover">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>Customer</th>
                <th>Membership Type</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
            @foreach (var customer in Model)
            {
                <tr>
                    <td>@Html.ActionLink(customer.Name, "Details", "Customers", new { id = customer.Id }, null)</td>
                    <td>@customer.MembershipType</td>

                </tr>
            }
        </tbody>
    </table>
}
```

**In Model**

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;
using System.Linq;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace Vidly.Models
{
    public class Customer
    {
        [Key]
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public MembershipType MembershipType { get; set; }
    }
}
```